# Understanding Admin Panel page paths [wordpress]

Tags: wordpress

path:

```
wp-admin/admin.php?page=nggallery-manage-gallery
```

Until now, I thought the value of the param "page" is the path to the file to be loaded (under the plugins directory).

Although, in the above case, there is no plugin called "nggallery-manage-gallery". Which means my understanding is wrong.

Could someone explain to me how wordpress decides which page to load in the admin panel, depending on the "page" parameter ?

Answer (score 0):

These types of pages are created whenever you use [add_menu_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page) or [add_option_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_options_page) in a plugin or in your `functions.php` file.

The `nggallery-manage-gallery` doesn't mean that there's a plugin with that name. This name is just the slug that have been assigned by [add_menu_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page) or [add_option_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_options_page).

If you search your `functions.php` and your plugin folder for `nggallery-manage-gallery`, you will find where that page is defined.